# Discord.py bot guild count

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the amount of guilds my bot is in, this is my current code:

```
@client.command()
async def servers(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{str(client.guilds)}")
```

But the bot just responds with `[<Guild id=739683588408082462 name='Epic bot testing' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=17>]`
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.guilds` is a list of guilds, so you just change `str` to `len` to get the length of that list.

```
@client.command()
async def servers(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{len(client.guilds)}")
```